# i have facing with error in Sencha Touch Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: touch

i am new to sencha touch technology.i have created sample app using IBMworklight +Sencha Touch .Which have a form with name textfield and button.i want store data in to MySQL when click on button.But when click on the button it gives me  error .i am unable to solve an error.i have attached .js file  [Form Code  !](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z875spe8wtrq0vf/insert.js)and Server Side Code here ["php & error code"](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0et4gh074jyfx4/insert.php).please help me.I  am waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Because of Cross Site Scripting restrictions in your browser you cannot access resources from a location other than the one that served the application. There are a couple of things you can do:

- serve your application assets as file assets (like Phonegap does)
- use JsonP for getting your data in
- use a local proxy that forwards your requests to a remote host (nice for development). EG. http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/

Comment: hi rob thanks for giving replay.can you give steps of how to enable CORS in chrome to use JsonP as you mention above.

Comment: Hi, well I can try, but the Sencha documentation says it all actually: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP

Comment: i read sencha docs.But it doesn't give proper information that where to put code.this docs create confusion to the beginner.i tried given code using model directory.finally it gives errors.

Comment: i used jsonp for sending data to the server and below is the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url : "http://test.com/form.php",
                    params : values,
                    method: 'POST',
                    withCredentials: false,
                    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
                    success: function (result, request){
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Thx','Form saved!');
                    form.unmask();
                    form.reset();
                    },
                    failure: function (result, request){
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Sorry', 'Error!');
                        form.unmask();
                    }
            });
```